# Form fields not retained on postback

Tags: c#, forms, postback, episerver

I'm developing a website using EPiServer. I have a form which submits to itself.
On submit, I check if there are any fields missing. If yes, then error message is shown.

The problem is that my fields are reset when submitted.

I could check this using jQuery, but I'm not. I'm cheking this from code behind.

I've tried setting `EnableViewState=true` sevceral places, but no luck.

Here's part of my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
  <asp:Panel ID="panelComplaint" runat="server">
    <li>
        <h3>Postnummer*</h3>
        <input id="senderPostCode" name="postCode" type="text" size="20" enableviewstate="true" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblPostCode" CssClass="missingField" Text="Mangler tekst" Visible="false" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Post sted*</h3>
        <input id="senderCity" name="city" type="text" size="100" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblCity" CssClass="missingField" Text="Mangler tekst" Visible="false" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="spacer10px"></div>
      <button type="submit" name="Send" >Send me</button>
    </li>
  </asp:Panel> 
</asp:Content>
```

What do I need to do, in order to retain form fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `runat="server"` to the input fields? As far as I'm aware, this is needed to ensure that asp.net round-trips data properly. I'm not sure if there's anything specific to EPiServer that would make that differ.

The `enableviewstate` attribute, unless it's specific to EPiServer, won't actually be doing anything.

If having the ID mashed up by ASP.net is a problem, consider upgrading to .NET 4.0, if you can, as this provides ways for you to control how the ID's are modified. If not, you could try placing a friendly translation into the page that you can then access via JQuery, for example:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function getSenderPostCode() { return eval('<%=senderPostCode.ClientID%>'); }

  var senderPostCodeField = JQuery('#getsenderPostCode');

  alert(senderPostCodeField.length());
</script>
```

That said, having "getSenderPostCode()" to reference would mean that you could probably skip the step with JQuery of getting a reference to it, so the following would work:

```
alert(getSenderPostCode().length();
```

By adding `runat="server"` to your controls you then wouldn't need to use `Request.Form["senderPostCode"].ToString()` to access the content of that field, you could instead access it directly:

```
var contentOfSenderPostCode = senderPostCode.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: If I do that, I'm not able to retrieve form values using `Request.Form["street"].ToString()`, because .Net changes the field name to `ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$RightContentPlaceHolder$senderStreet`...

Comment: Also, I'm not able to use `jQury('#myID')` - again because .NET creates it's own ID.

Comment: ok, thanks. (And some gibberish since comments must be 15 characters long...)